# What can I use for user to input time and Converting a value from an EditText to an Integer

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext

1) I want to get a time value from the user ,time as in amount of time in hours, minutes and seconds, without using an EditText field. I want to use something like TimePicker but without the AM and PM stuff. Just minutes and seconds. Does anyone know what I can use?

2) I want to convert a value from an EditText field into an Integer so that I will use it later in my code ie perform an operation like say multiplication. And I tried to parse it and it doesn't work. It instead shows an error. And I've seen some code about parsing a long and I figure it is a similar operation. Here's my code :

```
mins=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
secs=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
timeHours = Int.parseInt(hours.getText().toString());
```

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(String s)` will do the trick

Comment: Okay this worked. Thanks a lot ya'll who answered my question. Now my problem remains on my first question. I want a user  time value to enter w/o the AM/PM part just in form of hrs,mins and secs. Is there a field like  TimePicker i can use for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
    timeHours = Integer.parseInt(hours.getText().toString());
```

instead of

```
    timeHours = Int.parseInt(hours.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Okay this worked. Thanks a lot. Now my problem remains on my first question.

Answer (score 0):

may try this

```
String h = hour.getText().toString();

int hr = Integer.parseInt(h);
```